# Don't want Array ito combine values

Tags: php, arrays

I Have an array in PHP that looks like:

```
Array ( [2099:360] => 6-3.25 [2130:361] => 4-2.5 [2099:362] => 14-8.75 )
```

Notice there is Two Keys that are 2099 and one that is 2130.  I Have a foreach to remove the everything after the colon. the $drop is my array

```
$a = array();
foreach ($drop as $part=>$drop_a){
    $ex_part = explode(":", $part);
    $a[$ex_part[0]] = $drop_a;
}

print_r($a);
```

but when I print $a it displays only the recent value of the 2099?

```
Array ( [2099] => 14-8.75 [2130] => 4-2.5 )
```

Any Successions? How can I get it to display all of the values?

Thank You for Your Help

Comment: You can't store two values into a single key unless you assign an array to that key.

Comment: Sorry but the second 2099 will overwrite the first, you need to change key maybe. You can check with in_array if (as example) 2099 exist, in that case you can use a different key to store that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a multi-dimensional array to store this strategy:

```
$a = array();
foreach ($drop as $part=>$drop_a){
    $ex_part = explode(":", $part);
    if (isset($a[$ex_part[0]])) {
        $a[$ex_part[0]][] = $drop_a;
    } else {
        $a[$ex_part[0]] = array($drop_a);
    }
}
```

Your resulting data-set will however be different:

```
Array ( [2099] => Array ( [0] => 6-3.25 [1] => 14-8.75) [2130] => Array ( [0] => 4-2.5 ) )
```

It may be beneficial to you to preserve the second portion after the colon `:`

```
$a = array();
foreach ($drop as $part=>$drop_a){
    $ex_part = explode(":", $part);
    if (isset($a[$ex_part[0]])) {
        $a[$ex_part[0]][$ex_part[1]] = $drop_a;
    } else {
        $a[$ex_part[0]] = array($ex_part[1] => $drop_a);
    }
}
```

Now your result is a little more meaningful:

```
Array ( [2099] => Array ( [360] => 6-3.25 [362] => 14-8.75) [2130] => Array ( [361] => 4-2.5 ) )
```

Finally you can use alternative key-naming strategy if one is already occupied:

```
$a = array();
foreach ($drop as $part=>$drop_a){
    $ex_part = explode(":", $part);
    if (isset($a[$ex_part[0]])) {
        $a[altName($ex_part[0], $a)] = $drop_a;
    } else {
        $a[$ex_part[0]] = $drop_a;
    }
}

function altName($key, $array) {
    $key++; // Or however you want to do an alternative naming strategy
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        return altName($key, $array); // This will eventually resolve - but be careful with the recursion
    }
    return $key;
}
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [2099] => 6-3.25
    [2130] => 4-2.5
    [2100] => 14-8.75
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a key and a sub key for each entry, so just put them in a multidimensional array:

```
$a = array();
foreach ($drop as $key => $val) {
    list($key, $subKey) = explode(':', $key);
    $a[$key][$subKey] = $val;
}
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [2099] => Array
        (
            [360] => 6-3.25
            [362] => 14-8.75
        )

    [2130] => Array
        (
            [361] => 4-2.5
        )

)
```

You can traverse multidimensional arrays by nesting loops:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $subKeys) {
    foreach ($subKeys as $subKey => $val) {
        echo "$key contains $subKey (value of $val) <br>";
    }
}
```